# Multi-tenant resque, and avoiding one tenant clogging the queue

Tags: redis, background-process, resque, php-resque

We have a multi-tenant app that runs `resque` for background processing.

The issue we occasionally run into is when a single tenant performs *a lot* of background work within a very short period of time. This essentially clogs up the queue for a while -- every other tenant's jobs are delayed while we work through the backlog for this single tenant.

Yes, we can add more workers. But that's not really a "solution", it's more a band-aid that still results in a delay for other tenants -- just a shorter delay as we process faster.

Is there more multi-tenant friendly way to use `resque`? Or a more multi-tenant friendly background queue entirely?

We've looking at either:

- using a queue per tenant, and a worker per tenant (dynamically created queues?)
- modifying `resque` so that it somehow round-robins through a queue per tenant

We're just wondering if there's something we're missing / a better way...

Answer (score 0):

You could use your `Rails.cache` to maintain temporary job counters for each participant and assign the job to different queues depending on the number of active jobs.

You would need to subclass your jobs to support different queues and write a method that resolves to the correct class for the job. Something like:

```
class Worker

   cattr_acessor :tenant_id

   class Worker::Low < Worker
     @queue = :low
   end

   class Worker::High < Worker
     @queue = :high
   end

   def self.queued
      "#{name}::#{resolved_queue(tenant_id)}".constantize
   end

   def self.resolved_queue tenant_id
     count = job_count(tenant_id)
     if count > 1000
       'Low'
     else
       'High'
     end
   end

   def self.cache_key tenant_id
     "job_count/#{tenant_id}"
   end

   def self.job_count tenant_id
     Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key(tenant_id)){0}
   end

   def self.job_count_increment tenant_id
     Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key(tenant_id)){0}
     Rails.increment(cache_key(tenant_id)){0}
   end

   def self.job_count_decrement tenant_id
     count = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key(tenant_id)){0}
     Rails.decrement(cache_key(tenant_id)){0} if count > 0
   end
end
```

and then call `Worker.queued(tenant_id).perform` when you are running the workers and make sure that `Worker.tenant_id` is set on `before_filters` in the application. See [Resque Priorities and Queue Lists](https://github.com/resque/resque#priorities-and-queue-lists) for more information on queues and priorities.

You should call increment on job queue and decrement from within the job.

Ugly, but workable.

And can be made more dry by some metaprogramming - to extract these methods into a module and then make sure the queue subclasses are generated on module include.

Comment: The only issue with this is that it potentially pushes things into the queue out-of-order, right?  So if someone goes over that 1000 limit, then we start pushing stuff into the low queue. But once it processes it down to the 999 level, then we start pushing stuff into the medium queue again. So potentially we could have stuff that executed AFTER the initial large batch, but gets processed BEFORE the tail end of the large batch. Correct?

Comment: Potentially yes, but not likely as last jobs in medium will probably be processed after the first jobs in low